# How to copy datas from android internal memory to desktop via excel vba?

Tags: android, excel, vba, path, copy

Here is example code for open folder with shell function:

```
public sub OpenFolder()
      Shell("MY PC￦E￦Data￦Photo")
End Sub
```

Ordinary it works. but... it does not work well with Android.
Here is my code:
    public sub OpenAndroid()
      Shell("MY PC￦Galaxy W￦DCIM￦Camera")
    End Sub

Im continually trying to edit my article and I surely entered between my code line but in showing article my code line dont do carriage return... sorry for inconvinience maybe it is stack overflow web's problem

So, when I run above code
there are message that such a directory is none.

and, I can't use Copy Method with android directory.

this code :

```
Sub Copy_Folder()
'This example copy all files and subfolders from 
FromPath to ToPath.
'Note: If ToPath already exist it will overwrite existing files 
in this folder
'if ToPath not exist it will be made for you.
    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String

    FromPath = "C:\Users\Ron\Data"  '<< Change
    ToPath = "C:\Users\Ron\Test"    '<< Change

    'If you want to create a backup of your folder every time you run this macro
    'you can create a unique folder with a Date/Time stamp.
    'ToPath = "C:\Users\Ron\" & Format(Now, "yyyy-mm-dd h-mm-ss")

    If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
        FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
    End If

    If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
    MsgBox "You can find the files and subfolders from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath

End Sub
```

How can I solve this problem?

Now Im using keyboard control override and mouse control override to open and copy android data.

but I want to accomplish my goal by just giving Path information to my code.

Comment: `I want to accomplish my goal by just giving Path information to my code`. Well please do. What is exactly your problem?

Comment: `Now Im using keyboard control override and mouse control override to open and copy android data.`. Sorry. I have no idea what you are doing.

Comment: My Problem is,   shell command can perceive window directory, but cannot perceive android directory that is connected to desktop.

Comment: What do you mean with 'perceive a directory'?

Comment: shell command can open window directory but can not open android directory. I can only open it with CUI. Now I only able to open it with GUI, and i want to open from CUI

Comment: and, it seems that excel vba cant read data from network path. just my computer's path is readable. how I can solve this problem?

Comment: You still did not describe your problem to the point. And what is CUI?